# Unable to run an exe from a .NET script in a Docker container

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I have a .net 8 script which runs calls an exe file. The script is built via Jenkins which creates a Docker image, create an AWS stack and runs the task.

However, when the .net script tries to run the exe I get a permissions error:

```
Failed Message: An error occurred trying to start process '/app/example.exe' with working directory '/app'. Permission denied
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
#Pull a builder image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env

USER root

WORKDIR /app

# Copy solution over (.dockerIgnore excludes bin, obj etc)
COPY Tool/ ./

RUN ls -l

# Restore nuget packages
#RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet restore ./Project.Tool.sln --source "https://example.com/repository/nuget-group/"

# Build the solution
RUN dotnet build ./Project.Tool.sln -c Release --source "https://example.com/repository/nuget-group/" -o out
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app

# Copy publish output to final container
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
#COPY --from=build-env /Project.Tool/bin/Release/net8.0/ .

RUN chown 1000:1000 -R /app

WORKDIR /home/jenkins
USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Project.Tool.dll"]
```

The .net script calls the exe using the following method:

```
public static void RunCommand(string filename, string aguments)
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = aguments;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();

    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

The Jenkins file for running the AWS task is:

```
stage('Run Migration Tool') {
    environment {
        SUBNET1 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat ${lsMappingsFile} | jq -r .Item.mappings.M.privateAppSubnet3.S").trim()
        SUBNET2 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat ${lsMappingsFile} | jq -r .Item.mappings.M.privateAppSubnet4.S").trim()
    }           
    steps {             
        sh "aws ecs run-task \
        --cluster wmcs-application-cluster-${JENKINS_ENVIRONMENT} \
        --task-definition project-${JENKINS_ENVIRONMENT} \
        --launch-type FARGATE \
        --region ${REGION} \
        --network-configuration \"awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[${SUBNET1},${SUBNET2}]}\" \
        --overrides \"containerOverrides=[{name=Project}]\""
    }
}
```

I understand this is a permissions issue but I'm unable to figure out where I need to set permissions and for what.

I've tried adding the `chown` command for the `jenkins` user and while this command seems to run it actually causes my logging in CloudWatch to not reach the log group.

There are seemingly no logs when I have that line in place.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated!